# Múltiple inserción en laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Necesito insertar una cantidad grande registros (10.000 en promedio) cada hora a través de un endpoint en una api rest hecha en laravel, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma pero al ser el volumen de datos tan grande no es optima:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $readings = $request->json()->all();
    $cont = 0;
    
    foreach ($readings as $reading) {
        foreach ($reading as $campo) {
            $reading = new Reading();
            $reading->datetime = $campo["DateTime"];
            $reading->lectura = $campo["Value"];
            $reading->sensor = $campo["SensorName"];
            $reading->save();
            $cont = $cont+1;
        }
    }
    return response("Se han insertado ".$cont." registros exitosamente.", 200);
}
```

Recibo esta data a través de un array json de esta forma:

```
{
   "Readings" : [
                 {"DateTime":"2021-00-00 00:00:00","Value":"000,00","SensorName":"0000"},
                  .
                  .
                  .
               ]
}
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer una inserción múltiple que involucre todo el array json en lugar de iterar lo e insertar registro por registro?

Comment: Puedes hacer un chunk de lo que te llega y asi la inserción hacerla por bloques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la recomendación de BetaM, fragmente la data e hice inserciones mas pequeñas quedando de esta forma y quedando solucionado el problema.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    .
    .
    .
    $chunks = $insert_data->chunk(600);
    foreach ($chunks as $chunk)
    {
        \DB::table('readings')->insert($chunk->toArray());
    }
    
    return response("Se han insertado los registros exitosamente.", 200);
}
```

Comment: Que bueno tienes una solución, no olvides marcarla como aceptada y asi los demás sabrán que es la solución

Answer (score 1):

Segun la documentacion de laravel 8 puedes hacer algo similar a esto y esto evitara hacer el for loop que quiza sea lo que mas tiempo te este consumiendo

```
Reading::insert([
    ['email' => 'picard@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'janeway@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
]);
```

Te dejo el link para mas info solo que esta en ingles espero no te sea un problema https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements