# Insertar muchos registros en Postgres con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

tengo que realizar un programa en el cual se debe seleccionar un archivo de excel y grabar los registros en una base de datos.

El archivo tiene mas o menos unos 85000 registros.

El front end tengo hecho con angular, leo el archivo de excel y lo envio a un backend hecho con laravel para guardar en la base de postgres.

Pero tengo problema de conexiones por el tiempo de ejecucion,

El metodo que uso en laravel es el siguiente

```
 public function create(Request $request)
{
    try{

        $input = $request->all();
        DB::beginTransaction();
        //grabamos el detalle
        foreach ($input['detalle'] as $detalle) {
            $entidad = new Cobus($detalle);
            $entidad->save();
        };
          DB::commit();
        return $this->insertOk($input);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return $this->insertErrCustom(null, $e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Recibo el json con los registros del excel y dentro de un bucle lo envio a grabar uno a uno, aqui tengo una consulta hay como enviara postgres a un procedimiento almacenado el json completo, y ahi hacer el bucle y guardarlo, o como recomiendan hacer este tipo de insert

Comment: Usa una [consulta `raw`](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/postgresql-copy) para enviar el comando [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) a Postgre.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Múltiple inserción en laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438378/m%c3%baltiple-inserci%c3%b3n-en-laravel)